# radio button value to the controller from vf page

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
 <apex:selectRadio  id="Frequency" layout="pageDirection" value="{!frequency}"
                                      onChange="show(this.value)">
                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="Daily" itemLabel="Daily"></apex:selectOption>
                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="Weekly" itemLabel="Weekly"></apex:selectOption>
                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="Monthly" itemLabel="Monthly"></apex:selectOption>
                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="Yearly" itemLabel="Yearly"></apex:selectOption>
                    </apex:selectRadio>
```

here is the controller code

```
     public String frequency { get; set; }

     System.debug(frequency);
```

how can I get the value of frequency as selected on the list and whenever the selection is changed then frequency variable also updates in the controller?
thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try actionfunction or actionSupport

VF:

```
<apex:actionFunction action="{!MyMethod}" name="myFunction" />

<apex:selectRadio id="Frequency" layout="pageDirection" value="{!frequency}" 
    onChange="myFunction()">
```

Or:

```
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!MyMethod}" />
</apex:selectRadio>
```

Apex:

```
public void MyMethod(){
    System.debug(frequency);
}
```